# Using Keycloak and Devise for Rails authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid, omniauth

We need to implement SSO in our existing Rails app. So far, it uses Devise as authentication system. There are some guides explaining how to login via omniauth to third-party services - as in the devise wiki (https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/OmniAuth%3A-Overview), but we need to make our keycloak service only accessible by our Rails backend. Thus, we want to provide our own login and registration forms to make requests to Keycloak via controller (instead of redirecting to Keycloak and back to our services after login).

Is that possible with devise/omniauth? Mainly, I wonder if a remote sign up on Keycloak works with the omniauth gem. Does anybody have some good ressources to start with?

Comment: Did you find any related documents or have the solution?